# Doxygen - show header to include in namespace page

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a header file with free static functions inside a namespace which I want to generate a doxygen documentation for.

The functions are properly listed in the resulting HTML docs however there is no #include "myHeader.h" link at the top of the html page (to let the reader know which file to include). For class description files there always is but not for files that only have a namespace with free functions in it.

So my question is, how can I let Doxygen automatically add such an #include to the corresponding namespace-with-functions-only header file?

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: When still relevant, please post a small example.

Comment: We have the same issue and an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73550553/how-to-find-which-header-file-to-include-from-the-documentation