# How to find which header file to include from the Documentation?

Tags: drake

One simple problem that I usually encounter when writing C++ code with `drake` is after finding the proper function to use from the official documentation, the official documentation does not tell me which header file to include and I have to dig into the source code to find the declaration. For example, I find function `AddContactMaterical` from the doc but the doc does not tell which header to include. I have to dig into the source code and finally find that it is declared in `drake/geometry/proximity_properties.h`. Do I miss something in the doc? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very real problem. When looking for a *class* (say [ProximityProperties](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_proximity_properties.html)), the "Detailed Description" section includes `#include <drake/geometry/geometry_roles.h>`. However, the same doesn't apply for stand-alone functions, aliases, etc. For example, the page that has the documentation for [`AddContactMaterial`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/namespacedrake_1_1geometry.html#a06f08c367a0ef97e7fc397a8a44d49d8) doesn't include any information for include files. That's definitely a usability issue.

I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/17803) for this.